# Azure function 401 when testing through the azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I've been trying to get this to work and have run into a brick wall.

I have a c# azure function which I am trying to call from within the azure portal which has been zip deployed. When I attempt to call the function from the console it is returning a 401 as well as everywhere else I call the function from. The authorization level is set to anonymous and azure ad is turned on for the function. Is there anything I might be missing that might cause this sort of behavior?

[image]

The function executes with no errors within my local environment with all of the same settings, but after upload it throws a 401 for any request I send to the function.

Comment: Check if there's no Easy Auth Enabled: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad?toc=/azure/azure-functions/toc.json

Comment: Could it solve your issue?

Comment: That was it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> and azure ad is turned on for the function.

The error was caused by the Azure AD Authentication of your function.

To fix the issue, you have two options.

1.Navigate to the `Authentication / Authorization` of your function in the portal -> turn off the `App Service Authentication`.

2.Access your function via the Azure AD Authentication, e.g. in the browser, access your funtion url, it will let you to login your AAD account, after login successfully, you will be able to access it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I want to maintain the azure AD authentication turned on for the app. The redirect is not required in this case, however. The easy auth fix worked (comment above).

Comment: @missionearth I don't understand your meaning, the Azure AD auth you used before means easy auth, but you test the function in the function UI in the portal, that can't let you to authenticate your user account, so you got the error. In the production environment, the redirect url is need to be configured. So I think the option 2 meets your requirement. Or you mean you did not configure the Azure AD auth correctly previously?